# Как подружить Fiddler и Java?

Tags: java, proxy, прокси

Коллеги, никак не могу настроить Fiddler для перехвата http траффика из .jar приложения, уже и прокси в JVM насильно кормил и батником запускал, ничего не помогает, он просто игнорирует мои просьбы... (
Прошу помощи, ответа в интернете не нашёл.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureJavaApp

Comment: Каким образом в приложении из .jar создаётся http трафик. Подчиняется применяемая библиотека настройкам прокси JVM или системы? В крайнем случае можно воспользоваться вместо fiddler wireshark-ом. Кроме того в любом случае могут быть проблемы перехвата трафика на loopback-интерфейс (127.0.0.1 или localhost)

Comment: Отправляет GET запрос на сайт, принимает ответ и выполняет действие.

Comment: @Sergey всё что на winpcap`e перехватывает запрос успешно, но я не умею там менять его "на лету", как это делает Fiddler.

Comment: В данном случае важно как открывается соединение с сайтом. Fiddler работает как прокси, насколько я понимаю. Значит программа должна вместо сайта подключаться к прокси fiddler-а. Если в программе используется библиотека для http, которая понимает прокси, то по инструкции должно получаться. А если допустим открывается сокет и поверх него уже гоняется http, то тогда с fiddler-ом ничего не получится. Если только нет режима прозрачного прокси (transparent proxy).

Comment: Подскажите тогда, через какой софт можно сделать подмену контента "на лету", ТЗ:
Есть ссылка вида: http://example.com/load/pluginExtend.jar
Нужно чтобы по этой ссылке, программа получала:
http://myhost.com/load/custom.jar

Comment: Это более общий вопрос, чем дружба фидлера с жавой. Сделать новый вопрос по перехвату и модификации трафика. Сразу налетит  стая кул-хацкеров и пьяных сисадминов. От предложений не будет отбоя. Правда все они будут одинаково бесполезны.